# How to forward a response to a JSF page from Backing Bean?

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml, dojo, javabeans

Im currently working in a JSF project and stuck with an issue. I have a  requirement like,

1. I have a button. Clicking on the button should trigger a dojo dialog box where it will be having a "OK" and "Cancel" button along with an info message. Clicking on the cancel button will close the popup.
2. Clicking on "OK" button will submit the form in javascript by calling document.formname.submit().

The issue is the on submitting, i need to take the user to another page with the response. I mean forward not Redirect. If i use h:commandButton with action attribute, then the pop up appears and it submits the form without waiting for user action in the popup..

I want the fisrt button click should trigger javascript function and that "OK" should submit the form and forwards the response to another page.

Please suggest me how can i do this with my xhtml,javascript,backing bean and faces-config. If needed i will post some sample code also.

As of now i have like this,

xhtml

```
<h:commandButton id="viewBtn" type="button" value="submit" onclick="submidt()"/>
```

js:

```
function submidt() {
                var h = new dijit.Dialog({
                    title: "Hello"
                });
                var content = "<input type='button' onclick='document.searchSecurityForm.submit();' value='OK' /><input type='button' onclick='this.hide();' value='Cancel' />";
                h.attr("content",content);
                h.show();
            }
```

faces-config:

```
    <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/viewpage.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <to-view-id>/editpage.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

so these makes me to stay in the same page(View Page) with the response. I want to make the user to take to edit page.

Thanks in advance.
goG

Answer (score 0):

> If i use h:commandButton with action attribute, then the pop up appears and it submits the form without waiting for user action in the popup..

return false at the end of your javascript onclick method.

```
function submidt() {
    var h = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "Hello"
    });

    var content = "<input type='button' onclick='document.searchSecurityForm.submit();' value='OK' /><input type='button' onclick='this.hide();' value='Cancel' />";
    h.attr("content",content);
    h.show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. One issue got resolved. I mean i can able to stop the h:commandButton by showing the popup by returning false. Now i want to return true for "OK" button and "return false for that "Cancel Button in the popup. Pls help me out. I owe you..!!

Comment: coz the control leaves as soon as the dojo popup has shown. But i want to return true or false based on the buttons from the popup. I doubt whether it's possible only when i construct the form again in the dojo dialog content to submit the content?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand. It looks like you are manually constructing the input buttons in var content and they don't seem to call this function (submidt) ... so what is not working for you?